# Setting TFS 2017 builds to Partially succeeded

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have an orchestration build that we would like to set status to partially succeeded if it didn't do certain things. With Xaml builds, we could do it by setting the CompilationStatus and TestStatus of the build.

For Tfs Builds, I can am trying to it by setting calling the TFS Rest API to update the build result.

```
$query = [uri]::EscapeUriString("$tfsCollection$tfsProject/_apis/build/builds/$buildId`?api-version=2.0")
$request = "{""result"":""$result""}"
try {
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $query -Body $request
}
catch{
    Write-Output "StatusCode:" + $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ +
                "`r`nStatusDescription:" + $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
}
```

After the call, I can see that the ribbon of the build changes to orange indicating that is partially succeeded. However, it gets changed to succeeded when the Finalize Build step of build is run.

[image]

What should I do that the end build finishes with a status partially succeeded.

Comment: Enable control option "`Continue on Error`" for the specific step. But the premise is that normally the step will be failed if it didn't do certain things. The option will not work If the step past successfully in normal .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a task with its control options set to "Continue on Error". Whenever this tasks fails, your build will be partially succeeded.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes, throwing an exception from a task and setting it to "Continue on Error"  seems to have done the trick